# Calling a function from a subclass inside another subclass

Tags: c++, inheritance

Consider one superclass with two subclasses, each fulfilling different purposes.

```
class SuperClass
{
    public:

        // Some functions using SubClass1 and SubClass2
};

class SubClass1 : public SuperClass
{
    public:

        SubClass1() // Default constructor
        {
            // Initialize an instance of SubClass1
        }
    private:
        // Some variables
};

class SubClass2 : public SuperClass
{
    public:

        SubClass2() // Default constructor
        {
            // Initialize an instance of SubClass2 with an instance of SubClass1
        }
    private:
        // Some variables
};
```

How do I go about creating a member variable of type SubClass1 inside SubClass2, i.e. calling the default constructor for SubClass 1 in SubClass2?

Comment: Could you clarify please, do you wish to create a member variable of type SubClass1 inside SubClass2?

Comment: @FireAphis Yes, but I am not able to access the constructor from SubClass1 in SubClass2.

Comment: @mouduor holding a class-type data member and doing nothing is enough to *default-initialize* it

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide conversion constructor in SubClass2 which takes SubClass1 object. i.e

```
SubClass2(const SubClass1& x)
{
    //initialization
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Think about `SubClass1` and `SubClass2` as two unrelated classes. The fact that they have a common parent doesn't interest you here. You just create an instance as with any other object:

```
class SubClass2 : public SuperClass
{
public:

    SubClass2() // Default constructor
    {
    }

private:
    SubClass1 class1_; // The correct default constructor will be called automatically
};
```

Even if `SubClass1` doesn't have a default constructor, you will still be able to initialize it as a common member object:

```
class SubClass2 : public SuperClass
{
public:

    SubClass2() :
        class1_(...) // Initialize as any other member
    {
    }

private:
    SubClass1 class1_; // Assume it doesn't have a default constructor
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The question compared with the presented code is a little bit ambiguous, but if you want an instance variable of type `SubClass1` within each `SubClass2` instance, you would just do something like this:

```
class SubClass2 : public SuperClass
{  public:
     SubClass2 : sub1() {}
   private:
     SubClass1 sub1;
};
```

If, instead, you mean to be able to initialize a `SubClass2` instance from an existing `SubClass1` instance, see the answer by @ravi - you just need a conversion constructor.

If it's something else you're after, then please clarify...

Comment: I don't seem to be able to create the member SubClass1 sub1.
SubClass1 is apparently of unknown type (tested in Xcode)?

Comment: Are you making sure the compiler sees the definition (or at least a forward definition) of `SubClass` before it gets to your `SubClass2` definition? In the code listed in the question, the definition is definitely there, but perhaps in your real code you've forgotten an appropriate `#include` or something...

Comment: I have included the `SuperClass` header file in the `SubClass2` header file. Do I have to include the `SubClass1` header file as well? 
If yes, is there any other way to access the constructor without having to include both files?

Comment: Yes, you need to include the `SubClass1` header - the compiler needs to know what the class looks like in order to instantiate it. You could make both the headers for `SubClass1` and `SubClass2` include the `SuperClass` header though (with proper include guards added if you haven't already), so you would only have to include the subclass header directly...